# How do i add an layer to an Nural network in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

i want to add a layer to a Nural network programicaly it returned this error `TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

```
class Net(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

    def num_flat_features(self, x):
        size = x.size()[1:]  
        num_features = 1
        for s in size:
            num_features *= s
        return num_features


netz =Net()
print(netz)



netz = nn.Sequential([nn.Linear(10, 120), netz()])



print(netz)
`
```

The same error happend when i was loading it with `netz=torch.load()`

the line which seems to cause the error is :`netz = nn.Sequential([nn.Linear(10, 120), netz()])`

how do i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so there are several things.

Beginning with why are you calling `netz()`, you already instiantiated the object earlier with `netz =Net()`, so this make no sense.

Second thing, `nn.Sequential` expects `*args` as "constructor" argument, so you directly pass subclasses of modules: `netz = nn.Sequential(Net(), nn.Linear(100,100))` or you unpack them: `nn.Sequential(*[nn.Linear(100,100), Net()])`.

You can also add multiple modules using an `OrderedDict` as is well documented in the PyTorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) (**which you should consult by the way - it's there for a reason!**)

```
model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
          ('conv1', nn.Conv2d(1,20,5)),
          ('relu1', nn.ReLU()),
          ('conv2', nn.Conv2d(20,64,5)),
          ('relu2', nn.ReLU())
        ]))
```

You can also add a module with `my_modules.add_module("my_module_name", Net())` to an existing collection of ordered modules.